# How to Map JSON data from a REST API to Azure SQL using Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a new pipeline in azure data factory.
I created the dataset, one from the rest api (a public one):
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo

and then I created an azure sql table with columns shown in the screenshot

[image]

The problem, is that I dont know how to do the mapping, as this is a complex JSON object, I am limited with the Mapping Designer:

How do I map the date?

[image: f]

Comment: Can you show us what the data you expected are?  Something like how you want store these json data?

Comment: in the first screenshot there is the table columns, id, stock, date and value, thats basically it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use an ELT approach for these, calling the REST API with a Web task and storing the JSON in a SQL table and then shredding the JSON using SQL functions like [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Example pipeline:

[image: Example ADF pipeline]

The key to getting this approach to work is the expression on the stored procedure parameter.  This takes the whole JSON output from the Web task and passes it in to the proc.  This is a simple logging proc which inserts the record into a logging table:

```
@string(activity('Web1').output)
```

I log to a table and then shred the JSON or you could use `OPENJSON` directly on the stored proc parameter, eg

```
--INSERT INTO ...
SELECT
    CAST( [key] AS DATE ) AS timeSeriesDate,
    JSON_VALUE ( x.[value], '$."1. open"' ) AS [open],
    JSON_VALUE ( x.[value], '$."2. high"' ) AS [high],
    JSON_VALUE ( x.[value], '$."3. low"' ) AS [low],
    JSON_VALUE ( x.[value], '$."4. close"' ) AS [close],
    JSON_VALUE ( x.[value], '$."5. volume"' ) AS [volume]

FROM dbo.myLog
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(logDetails , '$."Time Series (Daily)"' ) x
--WHERE logId = 23333;
```

My results:

[image: My results]

Answer (score 1):

Does the data have a structure? If so, you can generate a dummy file, place it in sink and do a one time mapping. If not, you can Lookup on the file, iterate over the content in a For Each Loop Container and insert details on to a SQL table.

E.g.

```
insert <<your table>> 
select '@item().name', '@item().address.city', @item().value
```

The important thing to remember is to iterate at the correct array. Let me know if it's not clear. Not in front of a system right now, so can't add screenshots.

Comment: the link above has the son structure, and also in the sql screenshot you can see the columns, screenshots would be helpful whe you have some time :), thanks in advance.